# Single language (not english) rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a general question on single language rails applications. Does it make sense to name the tables in the language of the application (e.g. German)? Or should I translate my models into English. What is the right approach?

Comment: As a German I would advise against it, though I've honestly never tried it. Rails however in my opinion is wrapped very well around the English language using it for 'guessing' table names from models, knowing about singularization and pluralization of certain edge cases etc. Besides that, all docs in programming are written in English, and writing English will help you improve your language skills as a side benefit quickly.

Comment: I did use German table names in a project using inflections and it went well, but I guess it might be better to have a base in English, too. Just wanted to know if there is some best practice, if it comes to make decision here. Thanks for the reply!